# Owin pipeline branches run all middleware at first stage-marker encountered

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin, katana

When creating an (unbranched) OWIN pipeline, stage-markers are respected.

But when using a branched pipeline (with `app.Map` or `app.MapWhen`) all middleware in each branch runs at the stage of the first stage-marker encountered.

Is there any way to use stage-markers within a branch?

---

To illustrate the problem I'm using a modified version of the [Katana branching pipeline demo](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/BranchingPipelines/Startup.cs)

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("start-of-the-line");

    app.Map("/branch1", app1 =>
    {
        app1.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("took-branch1");
        app1.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("more-in-branch1");

        // Nesting paths, e.g. /branch1/branch2
        app1.Map("/branch2", app2 =>
        {
            app2.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("took-branch2");
            app2.Use<DisplayBreadCrumbs>();
        });

        app1.Use<DisplayBreadCrumbs>();
    });
```

For the path: `/branch1/branch2` this outputs the expected result:

> start-of-the-line (stage: PreHandlerExecute), took-branch1 (stage: PreHandlerExecute), more-in-branch1 (stage: PreHandlerExecute), took-branch2 (stage: PreHandlerExecute)

Now I add some stage markers:

```
    app.Map("/branch1", app1 =>
    {
        app1.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("took-branch1");
        app1.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

        app1.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("more-in-branch1");
        app1.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authorize);

        // Nesting paths, e.g. /branch1/branch2
        app1.Map("/branch2", app2 =>
        {
            app2.Use<AddBreadCrumbMiddleware>("took-branch2");
            app2.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostResolveCache);
            app2.Use<DisplayBreadCrumbs>();
        });

        app1.Use<DisplayBreadCrumbs>();
    });
```

This time the output for the same path is:

> start-of-the-line (stage: Authenticate), took-branch1 (stage: Authenticate), more-in-branch1 (stage: Authenticate), took-branch2 (stage: Authenticate)

Can anyone explain why everything runs at the `Authenticate` stage and whether there is a workaround to respect the other stage markers in branches?

Comment: By design. Stage markers are only supported in the root pipeline. Otherwise you may miss taking a branch.

Comment: @Tratcher: do you have a citation for this? I couldn't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: I don't know that it is documented, nor do I remember how I knew that 4 years ago. However, I'm the dev maintaining katana and trust it was right when I answered it. I can point you to the rough area of the code for your own inspection if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Surfacing the comment as an answer:

> By design. Stage markers are only supported in the root pipeline. Otherwise you may miss taking a branch. – Tratcher Oct 20 '15 at 1:19

So yes as the question states, "when using a branched pipeline (with `app.Map` or `app.MapWhen`) all middleware in each branch runs at the stage of the first stage-marker encountered."

*With that context, a note for using SignalR: when calling one of the SignalR OWIN extensions, such as `MapSignalR` or `RunSignalR`, those explicitly set the stage marker to avoid having a session state:*

```
// We need to make that SignalR runs before any handlers are
// mapped in the IIS pipeline so that we avoid side effects like
// session being enabled. [...]
builder.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthorize);
```

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.4.1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Owin/OwinExtensions.cs#L246

*This means that if you configure SignalR in your OWIN app, _all_ requests, including non-signalr requests, will run at that same stage, without `HttpContext.Current.Session` or `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`.*